# isearch but don't move the cursor until I ask to search

Tags: isearch

In a large file, I would isearch for the word `byebug`

but as soon as I type `by`, my cursor is moved to a line containing the word `bystander`.  (The file actually does not have the word `byebug`.)

But now
I'm a bit lost with my cursor at this random line. I didn't find what I was looking for (`byebug`), and I don't know how to get back to where I started searching.

This kinda sucks. Is there a way to either

a) tell search to not start until I've finished typing or

b) if I search moves my cursor to a partial match, how can I go back to where I was

Comment: Maybe you can try starting the search with `isearch-edit-string`? And, press return when you are done typing the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`C-g`, possibly repeating it, puts you back where you started and exits Isearch.

Not wanting search to start until you've finished typing is ***not*** incremental search.  It is plain, nonincremental search.  In Emacs you do it using `C-s RET`.

See the Emacs manual, node [Nonincremental Search](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Nonincremental-Search.html).

How did I find that help page in the Emacs manual?

1. `C-h r` to open the manual.
2. `i noninc TAB` to ask the Index about things nonincremental.

If you get to know the Emacs help commands then you can *ask Emacs*.

Comment: Note also that if you have exited isearch and want to get back to where you started from, you can simply pop the mark with `C-u C-SPC`